# Memory Layout of a C program (Phyical vs Logical view)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

As per my understanding, the logical view of the C program is divided into many segments such as

```
Code
Data
Bss
Heap
Stack (typical implementation: Heap and Stack growing in opposite directions).
```

How are these segments aligned in the physical memory?

As per my understanding, physical memory uses frames of fixed size to store the pages of the process.

If that is the case then what how is this actually consistent with the user view? Example: the stack and heap area might be distributed among many pages. Pages  might be scattered through the memory.

Comment: It looks like your question is about virtual memory in general. This has no relation to "C program" at all. This also has no relation to sections like "Code", "Data" or "Bss".

Comment: This depends in os and hardware

Answer (score 0):

> If that is the case then what how is this actually consistent with the
>   user view? Example: the stack and heap area might be distributed among
>   many pages. Pages might be scattered through the memory.

The virtual memory system maps "virtual" addresses onto physical addresses so that user code never knows or cares about where the memory it's using is located in physical memory. This is typically done using a hardware memory management unit (MMU), but it could also be done by the operating system without the MMU. As far as user code is concerned, there's just one nice big address space that's always available.